# C safe usage of scanf/freopen/fopen to read from text file into an array

Tags: c

My input is:
`5 1 2 3 4 5 6`
My expected output is this:
`10 2 4 6 8 10 12`

Generally, I want to read my input and store it in an array `arr`, given that I don't know how many numbers I have as an input, so I don't know when the lines ends, I should just keep reading.

I am using C for the first time, and I have tried to write a safe code. Specifically, I wanted to use `fopen` instead of `freopen`, I checked for return values of `scanf` and `fopen` and instead of `while(!feof(filepointer))` I did the one with `for(;;)` and `break`. My question is:

I run my code and it gives me an infinite loop, why?

Did I do good readings?

This is the code:

```
#define  MAX  100

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    // ....................read data........................
    FILE* inp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE* out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (inp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reopen stdin.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (out == NULL) {
        fclose(inp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reopen stdout.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int a, n = MAX, i = 0;
    //int* arr = malloc(sizeof * arr * length);
    int* arr = calloc(n, sizeof * arr);
    for (;;) {
        if (fscanf(inp,"%d", &a) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an int.\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            arr[i] = a;
            fprintf(stdout, "%d ", arr[i] * 2);
            i++;
        }
    }

    // ....................close - free........................
    free(arr);
    fclose(inp);
    fclose(out);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem 1: `FILE* inp = fopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);` and `FILE* out = fopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);` are wrong.  `fopen` takes two arguments, not three.  If you're setting up your own input and output streams (which is a fine idea), you don't have to do anything with `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: Problem 2: if you've opened `inp` for reading, you should be using `fscanf(inp, ...)` to read from it.

Comment: Problem 3: if you do `arr[i++] = a;`, then you've already incremented `i`, so the next line `fprintf(stdout, "%d ", arr[i] * 2);` won't act on the number you just read.

Comment: Ok, but can you specify what s wrong with problem 1?

Comment: Fix the problems mentioned in the comments. The recompile with all warnings enabled `-Wall -Wextra` and consider the warnings as errors. Fix them.

Comment: Thanks, but before that if you can see if I still have other problems with the code, I corrected what you mentioned.

Comment: is it necessary to do `fclose(inp)` ?

Comment: The line with `fscanf` should be `if (fscanf(inp, "%d", &a) != 1) {`. Look closely at the parentheses.

Comment: Anything that has been successfully `fopen`ed, should be `fclose`d.

Comment: The loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)`. Otherwise, you'll go past the end of the array when the file has more than `MAX` numbers in it. You don't really need the array anyways. You could just print `a * 2`.

Comment: Also, are there any illogical lines added that should not be neccessary?

Comment: @user21078706: After returning from `main`, all files are automatically closed. Therefore, calling `fclose` is not necessary. However, it still is good programming style. Generally, you should close a file when it is no longer needed. This can be the case long before the program exits.

Comment: Why not adding `fclose(inp)` here `if (inp == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reopen stdin.\n");`

Comment: @user21078706: In that case, opening the file failed. You cannot close a file that was not successfully opened.

Comment: I still get an error for this `arr[i] = a;` `Deferencing NULL pointer 'arr'`, why?

Comment: That would only happen if `calloc()` failed for some reason. You should check the value and abort if it fails.

Comment: Ok, what is the difference between `return EXIT_FAILURE;` and `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` ?

Comment: Consider making the loop `while(i < MAX && fscanf(inp,"%d", &a) == 1)`. If you need to know whether there was an actual error, you can check afterwards.

Comment: When used in function `main()` there is no difference between `return EXIT_FAILURE;` and `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: @user21078706: There is no difference between `return EXIT_FAILURE;` and `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` if these lines are in the function `main`. However, outside the function `main`, there is a big difference, because one line will end the program whereas the other line will only return from the currently running function.

Comment: @user21078706 "I am using C for the first time" --> OK, various errors, yet very good coding otherwise.  Enable all compiler warnings.  Once you get it "working", consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Note: `else `in `else { arr[i] = a;` is not needed as prior `if()` block did a `break`.